# How to override .phtml files in Magento 2 Tax module?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides

I want to override a .phtml file in following location, please guide me how to do that.

`vendor\magento\module-tax\view\base\templates\pricing\adjustment.phtml`

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to override the file through a module or a theme?

Comment: @Barbanet I'm trying to override with a custom theme

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `app/design/frontend/Your_Org/Your_Theme/theme.xml` with the following content:

```
    <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
        <title>Your_Theme</title>
        <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
        <media>
             <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
        </media>
    </theme>
```

Then copy the `adjustment.phtml` you'd like to override to `app/design/frontend/Your_Org/Your_Theme/Magento_Tax/templates/pricing`

Now just edit the `adjustment.phtml` there to get what you expected.